# calling js function in another .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the success callback function of my AJAX post, I'm trying to call a function that's in another JS file

page1.html contains:

```
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/page2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/dev/new/scripts/search.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"search_1":"<?php echo $item1; ?>","search_2":"<?php echo $item2; ?>"},
            success: searchResults()
        });
    </script>
</head>

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/dev/new/scripts/search.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"search_1":"<?php echo $item1; ?>","search_2":"<?php echo $item2; ?>"},
    success: searchResults()
});
```

page2.js contains:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function searchResults () {
        stuff...
    }

});
```

The error firebug is giving me is: "ReferenceError: searchResults is not defined"

Comment: I don't think you should put your function in $(document).ready

Comment: Because `searchResults` is inside your ready function, hidden from the global scope.

Comment: Why does page1.js file contain html? If you want to call js, you must include the js in html file using script src="/url/to/js/file"

Comment: @khattam - page1 is actually an html page, not JS...changed my question to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a function as the success handler, it needs to be specified like this:

```
success: searchResults
```

not like this:

```
success: searchResults()
```

When you put the parens after it, it instructs the JS interpreter to call it now.  When you don't put the parens after it, it is a function reference that can be called later by whomever has the reference.

---

Further, the `searchResults()` function is defined locally inside your document.ready handler and is NOT available outside that function (it is local to your ready callback).  If you want it available globally so you can call it from another context, you will have to define it globally.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have put the function definition inside document ready. Try after putting it outside.

Answer (score -1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. In page2.js, function `searchResults` is only defined after the DOM is ready. But the same is not applicable for the ajax call in page1.js. Which is why, when page1 looks for `searchResults` it does not find it. Wrap the ajax call in `$(document).ready()` as well, or remove both from `$(document).ready()`.
2. When you do `success: searchResults()`, `searchResults` gets evaluated, and it's return value is assigned to `success` which is not what you want. Do `success: searchResults` instead (without the parenthesis).

Comment: It's not that the `searchResults()` function is only defined after the DOM is ready.  It's that the `searchResults()` function is defined locally within the dom ready function callback and is ONLY available inside that callback function.  It is not available globally.